# How to pass an image from C++ to Java

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to pass an image (`PNG` file that it is only in memory and not on the hard-disk) from an old `C++` application to my `Java 8` application, but I'm not finding solutions. From my `Java` app, I call native functions in the `C++` DLL.

> In my Java app I suppose I should write something that works with an
>   array of byte.

```
public static native Byte[] getByteArrayImage()
```

In the C++ app I wrote this code

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_it_getByteArrayImage(JNIEnv * env, jclass obj, jint imagekind)
{
  AFX_MANAGE_STATE(AfxGetStaticModuleState());
  unsigned long bufferSize;
  BYTE* buffer = PaintToBufferImage(imagekind, &bufferSize);
  jbyteArray jb= env->NewByteArray(bufferSize);
  env->SetByteArrayRegion(jb, 0, bufferSize, (jbyte *)buffer);
  return jb;
}
```

Could you help me? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "pass"? Can't the Java program simply read the file?

Comment: I don't want to write the file on the hardisk, I'd like to pass directly from the C++ app to the Java app. I suppose with an array of byte... right?

Comment: So there isn't really a file on disk, just a PNG image in memory? That's quite important information that should have been in the question from the beginning. Please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Oh and don't forget how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt, and describe how it works or not works.

Comment: Sorry, I'll keep in mind for the next time. Just edited the question. Thank you!

Comment: If the image is in memory only - why do you need PNG format? Wouldn't it be easier just to pass the decoded raw data? Or do you want to profit from data compression?

Comment: I suppose it is better to use compression on the C++ side due to performance...

Comment: Admitted, lacking a bit of JNI experience, but your code seems to place the data into an array directly usable from Java (instead of sending it via pipe, socket or similar). So what do you expect to gain by compression? Be aware that encoding to and decoding back from PNG will *cost* performance...

Comment: If you pass a known format as an array of bytes, you can wrap it into `ByteArrayInputStream` on the Java-side, and read it from there (with `ImageIO.read()` for example)

Comment: @Aconcagua I need a PNG file because then I should send this to a browser. About "pipe and socket" could you tell me more?

Comment: @tevemadar, ok with ByteArrayInputStream, but do you know how to handle this on the C++ side?

Comment: If you render something in C++, and want it to send to a web client via a Java server, the Java part does not even have to decode it. Encode in C++ with any library you find (search for ***C png encoder***), emit a `Content-Type: image/png` header in the server and then the encoded image data. The server itself does not have to "view" the image, I assume.

Comment: @Koba With sockets or pipes, you'd write from with C++ and read from with Java. But the socket or pipe will *buffer* the data, so you copy data twice. This makes, in my eyes, the approach inferior to the JNI one, where you write data directly to where it is used.

Comment: @tevemadar yes, It is like this. Do you know how to produce a ByteArray in C++ that matches with ByteArrayInputStream to the Java side?

Comment: If you do not want to *decode* the image on Java-side, you do not need the `ByteArrayInputStream` at all. `write(byte[])` is available for any outputstream, so if you have the `byte[]`, you can forward it without further steps.

Comment: OMG, maybe I see it now: you have `Byte[]`, which is an array of [`Byte` *objects*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html). How about writing `byte[]` instead? That would be an array of `byte` primitives. Side remark: it would have been nice if you tell that this snippet does not work at all - so far everyone was discussing what to write into the array, and not about the array itself. It is a good practice to try sending some hardcoded simple thing (like the bytes of "hello") first, and verify if they arrive correctly.